# Android duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class while creating release apk

Tags: android, gradle

App runs fine on all devices/Emulator. but when i am trying to create signed release apk. i am getting this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForProdRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class

this project was being developed in eclipse before and recently i had converted it to android studio. everthing was wrking fine until when i am trying to create signed apk.

[image]

Comment: JAR files... That's your main problem. You should switch to proper Gradle dependencies

Comment: How come you have api16, api17, api19 and api23 in your dependencies?
please check your modules and compile them all with the api23

Comment: yea its a multimodule project. changing it to w3

Comment: @Cricket it does jave jar files will convert them into dependencies now

Comment: It may be worth checking out this post. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/95/gradle-for-android/2911/centralizing-dependencies#t=201607281403491043528

Comment: Thanks Cricket. i solved this issue by seting all api level to 23.thanks for ur advice @алекс кей